# Parse iOS Swift object key inside whereKey

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, swift2

Is it possible to run a `whereKey`on a `PFQuery` with object keys within? Let's say I want to fetch all users with a current score higher than their previous? Something like this:

```
query.whereKey("score", greaterThan: ?previous?)
```

In this example, what should I enter instead of `?previous?`? Of course I could fetch all users and then make comparisons but that will be slow with many users.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a Parse query can only compare a key against a provided object.

I would suggest making a `beforeSave()` cloud code event that compares the new score with the previous *upon saving* and then sets another column (i.e. `newHighscore`) to 1.

You can then query for all users with `newHighscore` equalTo 1.
Next time you save the user score, if it's not higher than the previous score, you set `newHighscore` to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But let's say I actually need the object key every time and I can't save it as a variable and compare it that way? In SQL, this would've been so much easier

Comment: Yes, this would be easy in SQL. Unfortunately, Parse have not included a solution for this use case in their API, although this topic has been discussed even here on SO for a few years.

Comment: Alright, thanks for you help. I will have to proceed with a lot more complex SQL queries, so Parse might not be the way to go, for me.